# Excel: if value is WB1 cell A1 matches any exact text in WB2 Column 1 then WB1 cell B1 equals corresponding WB2 Column B

Tags: excel

I am using two different Workbooks. for this example we will say WB1 and WB2.  WB2 has the information stored. For example in WB2 A1 has `99004422` and B1 has `Robert` and A2 has `90208888` and B2 has Joshua etc.. when I type `99004422` in A1 in WB1, I want the corresponding cell in column B from WB2 to auto generate. How can I accomplish this? 
[enter image description here][1]

WB2 with information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn6Ni.png

WB1 needs names generated form referencing WB2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keG6T.png

Comment: Try to do something with "VLOOKUP()", "INDEX(MATCH())" and "OFFSET()".

Answer (score 0):

So if in worksheet WS1 you already have the original data in column A (column 1) and B (column 2), here is a simply way to do this:

1. open both of your worksheets

assuming your original data goes from row 1 to row 20 in Sheet1 of worksheet WS1,

2. in first cell of column B of you worksheet WS2, write

   > =VLOOKUP(A1, [WB2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$20,2,FALSE)
3. Save and close.

Now if you open your WS2, and write anything in column A, it should provide you with a matching name in column B (where you entered the above). You can change any of the above based on your original data, and please note that if you open WS2 only, the formula will change a bit to refer to the other file through your computer network directories.
Good luck.